# How do I convert a single select drop down to buttons in React/JS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I had a drop-down for gender single-select: Male/Female

However, our designer wanted to spice it up and turn drop-down into buttons like this:
[image: Male and Female buttons]

How can I implement these buttons in Javascript/React where clicking on one button highlights it and then it unhighlights the opposite button?

Comment: Tell your designer to try to do it first, Then come back here and ask for help if they get stuck. This is not a coding service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned that Bootstrap has this functionality as long as you include the data-toggle="buttons" in the top div.

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary active">
            <input type="checkbox" name="options" autocomplete="off" checked> Option A
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="checkbox" name="options" autocomplete="off"> Option B
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary active">
            <input type="checkbox" name="options" autocomplete="off" checked> Option C
        </label>
    </div>
```